# How to add Global.asax page to asp.net 4.5 version in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to put css and javascript files as reference in aspx page from bundle(global.asax )file in 2013(4.5 version) visual studio. how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/AllStyles").IncludeDirectory("~/images","img.css")
                             .IncludeDirectory("~/content","con.css")
                             .Include("~/styles.css"))
```

In your view Page:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/AllStyles") %>
```

or

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/img").Include("~/images/img.css"))
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/content").Include("~/content/con.css"))
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/style").Include("~/styles.css"))
```

In your view Page:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/img","~/bundles/content","~/bundles/style") %>
```

And remind that you must add in the Global.asax.cs file this `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

Comment: How to get the order of .js file

Comment: `bundle.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mainJs").Include("~/Scripts/mainSite.js")` - for example